# Not reading all characters after seek

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, file-read

I'm trying to make a program that inserts log entries into a text file. The issue I'm having is that I read through the file line by line for a specific line and want to write before the line. Python correctly reads the line I'm looking for, however, when I seek to go back to the previous position, it does not read the entire line anymore. I checked the offset and it's exactly the same but for some reason the entire line isn't getting read.

```
def fileWriter():
    immediateTrigger = 0
    returnTrigger = 0;
    with open('C:\\testData.txt', 'r+') as file:
        for line in iter(file.readline, ''):
            #line = file.readline()
            if 'Beginning of text entries' in line:
                print('arrived at text entries')
                print(file.tell())
                print(line)
                immediateTrigger = 1
                file_pos = file.tell()
            while not line.strip() and immediateTrigger == 1:
                #print('here')
                prev_pos = file.tell()
                print(str(prev_pos) + 'before')
                newLine = file.readline()
                print(newLine)
                if 'Text Entry 25' in newLine:
                    file.seek(prev_pos)
                    print(str(file.tell()) + 'after')
                    print(file.readline()')
                    immediateTrigger = 0
```

The output I would get is:

```
arrived at text entries
Text Entry 1: The 1st revision
(random entries...)
36800 before
Text Entry 25: The 25th revision
36800 after
try 25: The 25th revision
```

Why does it cut off like this?

Comment: Do you see the appropriate output if you use `read(20)` instead?

Comment: Just tried it. It results in seeing more of the entry but still not the entire thing. The beginning is still cut off.

Comment: in the code there is no print statement between two print statements that print file cursor position before and after. but in your output there is one extra line of output. how is that possible?

Comment: This isn't exact output. Sorry about that, but the actual code contains work information I can't post

Comment: Missed a print statement in the code. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution. I'm not sure why but when I use rb+ as the mode instead of r+, it reads the entire line just fine.